# Algorithm: How to Delete every other file

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a folder with thousands of images.
I want to delete every other image.
What is the most effective way to do this?
Going through each one with i%2==0 is still O(n).
Is there a fast way to do this (preferably in Python)?

Thx

Comment: It's unclear what do you have and what do you want to get.
You want the delete every *other* image? Other in respect of what?
And what the hell is "i" in your "i % 2"? And what is n in O(n)??

Comment: Thanks, Mr. Obvious, for your great answer.
I want to know what quantity is expressed by N.

Comment: He's writing something to delete half the images in a directory... so, other than the number of image files, what *could* n be?

Comment: I've thinked that it is too moronic to pretend to erase n images in less than O(n) time, so it should be something different...

Comment: Just do [os.unlink(x) for x in os.listdir()[::2]] as mtasic answered - all the slowdown will be caused be IO, not your algorithm..

Answer (score 21):

To delete half the N images you **cannot** be faster than O(N)!  You *do* know that the O() notation means (among other things) that constant multiplicative factors are irrelevant, yes?

Comment: careful with that exclamation point there... I'm dyslexic and initially read it as "cannot be faster than O(N!)" which is obviously wrong... One should never get excited when doing math. you run the risk of exponential growth B-)

Answer (score 13):

```
import os
l = os.listdir('/some/dir/with/files')

for n in l[::2]:
    os.unlink(n)
```

Answer (score 3):

> Going through each one with i%2==0 is still O(n). Is there a fast way to do this (preferably in Python)?

The only way to be faster than O(n) is if your files are already sorted, and you only want to delete 1 file.

You said i%2==0, this means you are deleting every "even" file. O(n/2) is still O(n)

Answer (score 2):

I fail to see any conceivable way in which deleting `n/2` files could be faster than O(n), unless the filesystem has some special feature for deleting large numbers of files (but I don't think that actually exists in practice, if it's even possible)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to delete Log(n) files, there would be... You can store images in a database, though ( MySQL has a "blob" type, among several others, that will store your images). Then you could do it in O(1) if you named them smartly.

/edit
i hate how i have to use shorthand and bad grammar to get my answers in quickly!!!

if you're looking for a python equivalent of rm -rf *2.img *4.img *6.img *8.img *0.img, know that the computer still has to go through the entire list of files

Answer (score 1):

You could use `islice` from the `itertools` module. Here goes your example:

```
import os, itertools
dirContent = os.listdir('/some/dir/with/files')
toBeDeleted = itertools.islice(dirContent, 0, len(dirContent), 2)
# Now remove the files
[os.unlink(file) for file in toBeDeleted]
```

This is another form of doing what you want, although I'm not sure if it'll be faster. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

"Going through each one with i%2==0 is still O(n)"

Increment by 2 instead of incrementing by 1?

```
for(i = 0; i < numFiles; i += 2) {
  deleteFile(files[i]);
}
```

Seriously though: iterating through a list of files probably isn't the slowest part of your file deletion algo.  The actual deletion likely takes several orders of magnitude more time.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use something operating-system specific like:

linux:

```
@files = grep { -f "$dir/$_" && /*.H$/ }
unlink @files
```

Win:

```
$file_delete =~ /H$/;
rm $file_delete
```

to see if your os can do it faster than iterating in python.

use os.system(...) or subprocess.call(...)  to run these from python.